# delete duplicates in table using partion and where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2016

I have found that using the partition over rows method to be fastest for duplicating rows in large tables. I'm trying to use the same process to delete some duplicates, but now I have unique situation.

Basically I need to delete rows that are duplicated on all columns except one. However, the rows would be allowed to be duplicated if the excluded column was also duplicated but not if it is different.

For example

```
col1     col2     col3    col4
1        2        3       4
1        2        3       4
1        2        3       5
```

The first 2 rows would be allowed to stay, but the 3rd row needs to be removed.

Normally I would use the code below to delete rows that are duplicated on certain criteria, but I don't know how to account for my current situation.

```
delete x from (select col1, ROW_NUMBER() 
over (partition by col1 order by col1) As rn From table1) x 
where rn > 1
```

Thanks for any help.
Just FYI the table contains 226 Million rows.

Comment: If `col4` had the values `4`/`5`/`6`, then all three would be deleted, right?

Comment: Well, not exactly, I need to use the where clause to keep the rows where col4 = 4. Which I guess is the real question. How do I include the where clause.

Comment: I believe I have found the answer. I just need to include col4 in the select clause but not the partition clause so that I can reference it. As in "where rn > 1 and col4 <> = '4'"

Comment: Never mind, I don't have the answer. I don't want to have to specifically identify the value of col4. I just want the query to sort of group by each unique value in col4 and delete the duplicates that don't match that grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a count, not a row number:

```
with todelete as (
      select t1.*,
             count(*) over (partition by col1, col2, col3, col4) as cnt,
      from t1
     )
delete from todelete
    where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I don't want to include col4 in the partition.

Comment: @John . . . Based on your question, you do.